# How can I use jQuery to submit a form using Ajax and then get the output of the page it submitted to?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm learning PHP and JavaScript, and I'm building a blogging platform. I'm working on the comment system. I want to check if the name field matches any users in the database, and if it does, then I want to display a message that the name is taken.

Here's the page that contains the form. (fullpost.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
include ('functions.php');
connectDB();

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = queryDB('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='.$id);

$post = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<head>
    <title><?php echo $post['title']; ?> - SimpleBlog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".commentform").validate();


          });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<a href="index.php">SimpleBlog</a>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php
//post found, display it
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0) {
        echo '<div class="post">';
        echo '<div class="postheader">';
        echo '<h1>'.$post['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<h5>by '.$post['author'].' at '.$post['date'].' in '.$post['category'].'</h5>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<p>'.$post['fullpost'].'</p>';
        echo '</div>';

    //display comments form
?>
    <div id="commentform">
        <form action="commentsubmit.php" method="POST" class="commentform"/>
            <?php
            //if not logged in, display a name field
            if (!loggedIn()) {
                echo '<label for="author">Name: </label><br />';
                echo '<input type="text" name="author" class="required"/><br />';
            }
            ?>
            <label for="comment">Comment: </label><br />
            <textarea type="text" name="comment" class="required"></textarea><br />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="postid"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit" id="sendbutton" class="button"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php   
}
else {
    //no posts found
    echo "That post doesn't exist!";
}

$result = queryDB('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid='.$id.' ORDER BY date DESC');
$numcomments = mysql_num_rows($result);

//comments found, display them
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        echo '<h5>'.$numcomments.' Comment:</h5>';
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        echo '<h5>'.$numcomments.' Comments:</h5>';
    }
    while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<h6> by '.$comment['author'].' on '.$comment['date'].'</h6>';
        echo '<p>'.$comment['text'].'</p>';
    }       
}
else {
    //no comments found
    echo '<h4>No comments</h4>';
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the page it submits to. (commentnew.php)

```
<?php
//creates a new comment

include('functions.php');

//form submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //set $author if not logged in
    if(!loggedIn()) {
        //check if username is taken
        connectDB();
        $result = queryDB("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['author']."'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            die('That name is taken!');
        }
        else {
            //username is not taken
            $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
        }
    }
    else {
        //user is logged in, set author to their username
        $author = $_SESSION['username'];
    }

    //$author is set, submit
    if (!empty($author)) {
        $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postid']);
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
        $date = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d")." ".date("H:i:s"));

        queryDB('INSERT INTO comments (postid,date,author,text) VALUES ("'.$postid.'","'.$date.'","'.$author.'","'.$comment.'")');
        echo 'Comment Sent!';
    }
}
?>
```

I tried using $.ajax in the script tags, but it seems to do nothing. Can I get an example of how to properly use it? How do I get it to pull the message from commentnew.php? Am I going about checking for the username the wrong way? Should I be using jQuery's validation plugin somehow?

Comment: Use FF + Firebug. Open the NET tab and see what is happening to your AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("form.commentform").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $.post({
     url: $(this).attr('action'),
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     success: function(reponse){
       //here response will contain whatever you send from the server side page
     }
   });
}):
```

Comment: Should I be putting that into the head in $(document).ready? When I do that, it makes the validation plugin not work and it doesn't send using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

in general:

```
var form = $("form.commentform");
$.post(form.attr('action') , form.serialize(), function(data) {
    alert("Response: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into jquery ajax function. That's what I use. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/